# Why is my view not resizing after rotating?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm only supporting the portrait orientation, but both the right-side-up and upside-down versions.  Why do my subviews not resize appropriately?  There's a status bar sized black space at the top of the view.  If I change tabs and come back, it's corrected.

http://www.irovr.com/img/temp/stackoverflow2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your frames to make sure that you are not copying parent frames. More than likely one of them is automatically adjusting for the status bar and the child views are accidentally copying the offset.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to all of this.  What do you mean by check your frames?

Comment: Check the .frame property for each subview. One of them will have the wrong offset which might be what pushing your views down like that.

Comment: Thanks.  I've gotten it part of the way I think.  After the rotation, I'm setting the frame like so...

    tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 480);

This keeps everything looking good, but when I'm in UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown the lower half of the tab bar buttons do not respond to touches.

Comment: There is a problem in the simulator that affects the "top" most pixels which would be the bottom of an upside down screen. I would check to see if it has the same problem on a physical device. If it does, check the parent view of the tabBarController to make sure its frame is also correct.